# C++ static_cast< int > (str.size()-1) means?

Tags: c++, casting

I am getting stuck when using this line and not able to understand.

Can Anybody tell me what is the mean of

```
while(i < static_cast<int>(str.size() - 1))
```

in the Following Code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < static_cast<int>(str.size() - 1)) {
        if(i > -1 && str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
            str.erase(i,2);
            i--;
        } 
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(str.empty())
       cout << "Empty String" << endl;
    else
       cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: You *do* know about `while` loops? Do you know what [`str.size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns? Do you know about [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)? If you know about all these things separately, then just put that knowledge together.

Comment: Do you know what a cast is ?

Comment: Some programmer dude ya i know loops but tell me what this "static_cast< int > (str.size()-1) " doing in this code

Comment: This code is awful . Someone probably wrote the cast to silence a compiler warning but they broke the code in the process

Comment: @dreamstracker, don't forget to accept the answer you think that answered your question to help future users finding most accurate one for the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare a **signed** and an **unsigned** integer, the compiler would warn you for that. E.g. [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) would show the following warning message:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
>   [-Wsign-compare]

The `std::string::size` returns an **unsigned integer**, an [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is an implementation-defined type and it *can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type*.

If you want to suppress these warnings, you have to cast the **signed integer** to **unsigned** before comparison. The code snippet you questioning does the opposite: casts (with [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)) the `std::size_t` (unsigned) type to `int` (signed) type. **This is a bad practice** because if the `str.size() - 1` is higher than [`INT_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/), it will produce an *implementation-defined* behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`str.size()`: take the size of a string. return type is size_t
`str.size()-1`: take the size minus 1. still size_t
`static_cast< int > (str.size()-1)`: cast the size_t to an int. so trim overflow binary digits if `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)` or left pad with zeros if `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)`, and treat as signed integer rather than unsigned.

Comment: tell me in non technical way just give simple answer what they are doing ??

Comment: The behaviour in case of "overflow digits" is implementation-defined. Not safe to rely on "trim"

Comment: @dreamstracker: "tell me in a non-technical way" - you're learning programming, which is absolutely a technical skill. You better get used to that.

Answer (score 0):

What it does?

It takes `str`'s size, and subtracts 1 from it. Then, it converts the resulting number to `int`. Then it compares this number to `i`.

**Why** does it convert it? If it didn't do it, an unsigned number would be compared to a signed one. There are rules for this case in the standard, but they are complex, and depend on the `sizeof`'s of `int` and `size_t`. You'd better not compare a signed number to an unsigned. A compiler usually warns you about it.

How could it be a problem? Consider, what if `str.size()` returns 0. Then, applying -1 on it, it becomes a huge number, SIZE_MAX. So this loop wouldn't work as intended (it would loop a lot of times instead of skipping the loop entirely, so it would crash), if the cast wouldn't be there.

Note that this code has a potential bug of using `int` here. It's because, if `str.size()` contains a number, which doesn't fit into an `int`, the program will misbehave. It should have used `size_t` for `i`, and use `while (i+1<str.size())` instead.

To me, the decision of using unsigned numbers for `size()` methods, is one of the design mistakes of the standard library (I know that a lot of people think differently, but this is my opinion).